# Sending JSON objects to web service in Android creates duplicate JSON Objects

Tags: java, android

I have created an android application to send JSON objects from my application to web service.

I'm able to send data to a web service.

**How to solve the problem**, that the web service is showing **duplicate** JSON objects?

Here is my code:

```
// Vehicle Condition Details taken Activity 

public class VechileConditionActivity extends Activity {

EditText Kms,Fuel,Regno,Licence;
RadioGroup oilRadioGroup,tyreRadioGroup,treadRadioGroup;
String Mileage,Fuellevel,Oillevels,Pressure,deapth,Vehiclenumber,Licencenumber;
private ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.vechilecondition1);
    Kms = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
    Fuel = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText2);
    Regno = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText3);
    Licence = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    //Taking action bar control
    actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Set the action bar properties includes Title,Icon,Background 
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setIcon(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.vehiclecondtion));
    actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.titlebar));
    // Set Bottom Action bar with background image
    actionBar.setSplitBackgroundDrawable(getApplicationContext().getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.footer));


        oilRadioGroup =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);



        oilRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                        RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(arg1);

                        Oillevels = radioButton.getText().toString();

            }
        });

        tyreRadioGroup =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup3);

        tyreRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(arg1);

                Pressure = radioButton.getText().toString();
            }
        });

        treadRadioGroup =(RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup2);

        treadRadioGroup.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup arg0, int arg1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
             RadioButton radioButton = (RadioButton)    findViewById(arg1);


             deapth = radioButton.getText().toString();

            }
        });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}

//onOptionsItemSelected  is called whenever an item in your options menu is selected
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    // case to upload the vehicle condition details 
    case (R.id.itemid_0):

         new sendJson().start();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "uploading the information", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    // case to capture the vehicle 
    case (R.id.itemid_1):
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    //Extract the data…

    String Driverid = bundle.getString("Driverid");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "capturing details of drivercode "+Driverid,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        break;
    // case to move to home screen to download the delivery list    
    case (R.id.itemid_2):

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setClass(getApplicationContext(), HomeScreenActivity1.class);
        startActivity(intent);

        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
public class sendJson extends Thread
{

    // declared locally so that it destroys after serving its purpose

JSONObject jsonobj = new JSONObject();
public void run() { 
try {
     HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
     HttpPost post = new HttpPost("http://XXXXX/XXXXXX");
     Looper.prepare(); //For Preparing Message Pool for the child Thread

     HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(client.getParams(), 10000); //Timeout Limit
        // adding some keys


     Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
     //Extract the data…

    String Driverid = bundle.getString("Driverid");//this is for String 

    String Mileage = Kms.getText().toString();
    String Fuellevel = Fuel.getText().toString();
    String Vehiclenumber = Regno.getText().toString();
    String Licencenumber = Licence.getText().toString();
    String Oil = Oillevels;
    String Air = Pressure;
    String tread = deapth;
    jsonobj.put("DriverCode", Driverid); 
    jsonobj.put("MileageReading",Mileage );
    jsonobj.put("FuelLevel",Fuellevel);
    jsonobj.put("VechileNum",Vehiclenumber );
    jsonobj.put("LicenceNum",Licencenumber );
    jsonobj.put("OilLevel",Oil );
    jsonobj.put("TyrePressure",Air );
    jsonobj.put("ThredDepth",tread );

    Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "DriverCode:"+Driverid);
    Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "MileageReading:"+Mileage);
    Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "FuelLevel:"+Fuellevel);
    Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "VechileNum:"+Vehiclenumber); 
    Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "LicenceNum:"+Licencenumber);
    Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "OilLevel:"+Oil);
    Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "TyrePressure:"+Air);   
    Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "ThredDepth:"+tread);

    StringEntity se;
    try {
        se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());

        se.setContentType("application/json");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        InputStream inputStream =    response.getEntity().getContent();
        HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(post, new BasicHttpContext()); //For thread safe
        String response1 = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
        response1 = response1.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
        Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "Server Response : " + response1);
        Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "Server Response : " + response1);
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block 
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    } catch (JSONException ex) {
        //buildref.setText("Error Occurred while building JSON");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }    
}

}
```

Comment: What steps have you taken to debug this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How do you know that the web service is receiving duplicate json objects?

Are you looking directly at the web service or just the app's log?

Because you created two identical logs:

```
Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "Server Response : " + response1);
Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "Server Response : " + response1);
```

Comment: should probably add this to the comments and remove as it's not an answer

Comment: I know but i dont have the 50 reputation points needed to add a comment

Comment: I'm sending the data from Android application to Sap Table.In the table i'm able to see the receiving of duplicate objects sap service is working fine but problem is with this code

Answer (score 1):

Got my answer the error which I made in my code is:

```
try {
        se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());

        se.setContentType("application/json");
        se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
        post.setEntity(se);
        HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
        InputStream inputStream =    response.getEntity().getContent();
        HttpResponse httpresponse = client.execute(post, new BasicHttpContext()); //For thread safe
        String response1 = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
        response1 = response1.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
        Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "Server Response : " + response1);
        Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "Server Response : " + response1);
}
```

This is the right code

```
try {
        se = new StringEntity(jsonobj.toString());

    se.setContentType("application/json");
    se.setContentEncoding(new BasicHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_TYPE, "application/json"));
    httppostreq.setEntity(se);
    HttpResponse httpresponse;
    try {
        httpresponse = httpclient.execute(httppostreq,new BasicHttpContext());
        String response1 = EntityUtils.toString(httpresponse.getEntity());
        response1 = response1.replaceAll("\\\"", "\"");
        Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "Server Response : " + response1);
        //Log.i("coooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooood", "Server Response : " + response1);

}
```